# convert C++ istringstream usage to C#

Tags: c#, c++

I am rewriting some code and wondering how I can convert this from C++ to C#:

```
istringstream vertexString = new istringstream(s);

//number of vertices
int numVertices;
vertexString>>numVertices;
```

Comment: What exactly is `s`?

Comment: s is just a string of some arbitrary data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to a static string utility class:

```
public static Stream ToStream(this string str)
{
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
    StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
    writer.Write(str);
    writer.Flush();
    stream.Position = 0;
    return stream;
}
```

Use like this. s must be string.

```
int numVertices;
using (var stringStream = s.ToStream())
{
    stringStream>>numVertices;
}
```

Comment: So the idea is to add my own functions onto the String class to simulate the c++ functionality. How do I go about declaring the utility Class though? I've heard about but never seen it done before. It would be an extension method right?

Comment: You can make regular function which return Stream. Or without function and using but code is not beauty and useful soo well. You don't add function too String class. Add too your main class.